# Objective-c : show information in detailView when you click on table row

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have some information in my table that I got them from server, I want to have them in my detail view when I clicked on a row, would you please help me in this implementation?

Here is my didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
TestDetailView *c = [[TestDetailView alloc] init];
c = [_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is TestDetailView ?  Looks like your code is allocating and initialising it and then setting it to be the object in _data.  Presumably the latter is data of some sort, may a string or a number.  You need to create a Label or textField in your TestDetailView and do something like c.textField.text = [_data objectAtIndex:row].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
TestDetailView *c = [[TestDetailView alloc] init];
c = self.data[indexPath.row];
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
TestDetailView *c = [[TestDetailView alloc] init];
[c setData:[subComponents objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
```

Comment: @Michael Petrotta thanks for edited, would you please help me, No visible interface for "NSArray declares the selector 'objectAtIndexPath'"

Comment: Sorry I thought of that afterwards. The array is looking for a row number not an index which has a section and row. Try        [c setData:[subComponents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];